# A simple JavaScript Function refuses to work due to strange Error

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following function "tomorrow_date" that refuses to work returning me the following error, while the function "today_date" works just as fine...

> TypeError: Cannot find function in in object 8. (RhinoScriptRunner.run#1819)

This is the non-working function and its respective code:

```
    function tomorrow_date() {
    var $current_year  = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
    var $current_month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var $current_day   = new Date().getUTCDate() + 1;

    if($current_day == 31 && $current_month.in(01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12)) {
        if($current_month == 12) {
            $current_day   = 01;
            $current_month = 01;
            $current_year  =+ 1;
        } else {
            $current_day = 01;
            $current_month =+ 1;
        }
    } else if($current_day == 30 && $current_month.in(02, 04, 06, 09, 11)) {
        $current_day = 01;
        $current_month =+ 1;
    }

    if($current_month.toString().length == 1) {
        var $saver = $current_month.toString();
        $current_month = "0";
        $current_month = $current_month + $saver;
    }

    var $unified_tomorrow = $current_year.toString() + "-" + $current_month.toString() + "-" + $current_day.toString();
    return $unified_tomorrow;
}

var $static_task_activity_date = tomorrow_date();
_alert($static_task_activity_date);
```

My question is, why does executing my "tomorrow_date" returns me such strange error?

Although, the following "today_date" function below, is executed just as fine without any problem.

```
    function today_date() {
    var $current_year  = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
    var $current_month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var $current_day   = new Date().getUTCDate();

    if($current_month.toString().length == 1) {
        var $saver = $current_month.toString();
        $current_month = "0";
        $current_month = $current_month + $saver;
    }

    var $unified_today = $current_year.toString() + "-" + $current_month.toString() + "-" + $current_day.toString();
    return $unified_today;
}

var $today_date = today_date();
_alert($today_date);
```

Comment: change $current_month.in(01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12) to [01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12].includes($current_month)

Comment: One thing to note is that `01` is not a valid number; remove the leading `0` and just write `1`.

Comment: `$current_month.in` is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your replies helped me, and I have created a flawless code to always dynamically obtain Tomorrow's Date 100% right:

- Tomorrow day was fixed by changing 30 to 31, and 31 to 32;
- Added recommended fix for Month in IF's, and it worked;
- Removed the UTC unnecessary tags in the JavaScript date functions;
- And lastly but most importantly, added dynamic February rule to detect 28 (29 code) days in common years, and 29 (30 code) in leap years.

> Tomorrow's Date:

```
function tomorrow_date() {
    var $current_year  = new Date().getFullYear();
    var $current_month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var $current_day   = new Date().getDate() + 1;

if($current_day == 32 && [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12].indexOf($current_month) >= 0) {
    if($current_month == 12) {
        $current_day   = 01;
        $current_month = 01;
        $current_year  = current_year + 1;
    } else {
        $current_day = 01;
        $current_month = $current_month + 1;
    }
} else if($current_day == 31 && [4, 6, 9, 11].indexOf($current_month) >= 0) {
    $current_day = 01;
    $current_month = $current_month + 1;
} else {
    var $year_type_total_days = (($current_year % 4 === 0 && $current_year % 100 > 0) || $current_year %400 == 0) ? 366 : 365;

    if($current_day == 29 && [2].indexOf($current_month) >= 0 && $year_type_total_days == 365){
        $current_day   = 01;
        $current_month = 03;
    } else if($current_day == 30 && [2].indexOf($current_month) >= 0 && $year_type_total_days == 366) {
        $current_day   = 01;
        $current_month = 03;
    }
}

if($current_month.toString().length == 1) {
    var $saver = $current_month.toString();
    $current_month = "0";
    $current_month = $current_month + $saver;
}

if($current_day.toString().length == 1) {
    var $saver = $current_day.toString();
    $current_day = "0";
    $current_day = $current_day + $saver;
}

var $unified_tomorrow = $current_year.toString() + "-" + $current_month.toString() + "-" + $current_day.toString();
return $unified_tomorrow;
}
```

> Today's Date:

```
function today_date() {
    var $current_year  = new Date().getFullYear();
    var $current_month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var $current_day   = new Date().getDate();

    if($current_month.toString().length == 1) {
        var $saver = $current_month.toString();
        $current_month = "0";
        $current_month = $current_month + $saver;
    }

    if($current_day.toString().length == 1) {
        var $saver = $current_day.toString();
        $current_day = "0";
        $current_day = $current_day + $saver;
    }

    var $unified_today = $current_year.toString() + "-" + $current_month.toString() + "-" + $current_day.toString();
    return $unified_today;
}
```

Comment: This is currently working 100%, thank you all for the great feedback! =)

Answer (score 1):

Executing `new Date().getMonth() + 1` gives you number 8 as a result, so `$current_month` becomes `8`. And trying to execute `$current_month.in(01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12)` you getting the error. Instead you may do following check

```
[01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12].indexOf($current_month) > -1
```

Comment: So how would you fix it?

Comment: oops, should be > -1 :)

Comment: @JonasBerlin yep

Comment: Thank you friend! Very well visualized

Comment: The problem with your code was that $current_month is a Number and a Number does not have a method called "in".

Comment: The mozilla MDN reference is a good place to learn about basic JavaScript objects - here is the documentation for Number: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Answer (score 1):

Change this from

```
if($current_day == 31 && $current_month.in(01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12))
```

to

```
if($current_day == 31 && $current_month in [01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12])
```

The ***in*** keyword is an operator not a function and works on arrays.
So you need to change that everywhere where you use the in operator.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "in" function for arrays, that is not correct. ["in" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is used to know if properties exist in an object.
You can use the ["indexOf" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to look for values inside an array.
So you should switch in for indexOf and validate against the value's index returned value.

PS: Your code logic will return incorrect values when the month is February. Frebruary value is 02, and it will never get to $current_day = 30. February has 28 or 29 at maximum. You need to fix that in your code.

Check this snnipet using your current logic and indexOf function.

```js
    function tomorrow_date() {
    var $current_year  = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
    var $current_month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var $current_day   = new Date().getUTCDate() + 1;

    if($current_day == 31 && [01, 03, 05, 07, 08, 10, 12].indexOf($current_month) >= 0) {
        if($current_month == 12) {
            $current_day   = 01;
            $current_month = 01;
            $current_year  =+ 1;
        } else {
            $current_day = 01;
            $current_month =+ 1;
        }
    } else if($current_day == 30 && [02, 04, 06, 09, 11].indexOf($current_month) >= 0) {
        $current_day = 01;
        $current_month =+ 1;
    }

    if($current_month.toString().length == 1) {
        var $saver = $current_month.toString();
        $current_month = "0";
        $current_month = $current_month + $saver;
    }

    var $unified_tomorrow = $current_year.toString() + "-" + $current_month.toString() + "-" + $current_day.toString();
    return $unified_tomorrow;
}

var $static_task_activity_date = tomorrow_date();
console.log("Tomorrow's date: " + $static_task_activity_date);
```

Answer (score -1):

How to read errors?
Before the list, let’s quickly look at the structure of an error message. Understanding the structure helps understand the errors, and you’ll have less trouble if you run into any errors not listed here.

A typical error from Chrome looks like this:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
The structure of the error is as follows:

Uncaught TypeError: This part of the message is usually not very useful. Uncaught means the error was not caught in a catch statement, and TypeError is the error’s name.
undefined is not a function: This is the message part. With error messages, you have to read them very literally. For example in this case it literally means that the code attempted to use undefined like it was a function.
Other webkit-based browsers, like Safari, give errors in a similar format to Chrome. Errors from Firefox are similar, but do not always include the first part, and recent versions of Internet Explorer also give simpler errors than Chrome – but in this case, simpler does not always mean better.

Now onto the actual errors.

Courtesy of davidwalsh. Hope it helps.